# How to get the name of a dependency property

Tags: c#, silverlight, dependency-properties

For binding purposes, we have a method that returns the most common dependency property for the framework element that was passed in.  If we pass in `TextBlock`, this method returns `TextBlock.TextProperty`; `RadMaskedTextBox` returns `RadMaskedTextBox.MaskedTextProperty`, and so on.

While debugging, if type `dp.Name`, I get "Text", "MaskedText" respectively.  But the `dp.Name` is not available in code.

I'm trying to do dynamic binding to a tooltip:

```
var binding = new Binding("Text")  //Works
{
    Source = frameworkElement
};

var binding = new Binding("MaskedText")  //Works
{
    Source = frameworkElement
};

var binding = new Binding(dp.Name)  //Doesn't work
{
    Source = frameworkElement
};
```

I can't figure out how to get "Text" or "MaskedText" from the dependency property, nor do I understand why it's hidden to begin with.

.Net Framework 4.5 / Silverlight 5

Thanks for any help or insight you can give!!
JD

Kevin, Thank you so much, you were pretty close.  It's a non-public field, so I did this:

```
{
var dpType = dp.GetType();
var nameField = dpType
                .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Single(pi => pi.Name == "Name");

var name = nameField.GetValue(dp);
}
```

However, I get an FieldAccessViolation when I call nameField.GetValue(dp).  I can see it in the watch, but can't actually get to it.  I wish someone would explain this, because I don't understand why I should not be able to get/use this value.  Especially when that (the string "MaskedText") is what has to supplied for the path.  UGH!!!

But thank you very much for your help!
JD

Comment: Where are you typing `dp.Name` at during debugging? The intermediate window at a breakpoint?

Comment: What is `dp`, where do you initialize it?

Comment: it's initialized from calling our method:
var dp = ControlPropertyResolver.Resolve(typeof(TextBlock)); //returns the dependencyProperty TextProperty.  

At a breakpoint after the call, I can type dp.Name in the Watch window and get a value of "Text"

Comment: When you say `// Doesn't work`...  does it not compile or is the .Name property is not the right value?

Comment: when writing the code dp has no properties, only a few methods; so dp.Name will not compile.  But when I hit a break point and add dp to the watch; dp.Name returns "Text" which is what I need.  It's very strange.  Name on a DependencyProperty is Non-Public property, I just don't understand why.

Comment: OK then take a look at my reflection answer which should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what is going on without further clarification... But making some assumptions it should be possible to get the name via reflection...

```
var typeOfDp = dp.GetType();
var nameProperty = typeOfDp
                    .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .Single(t => t.Name == "Name");
var name = nameProperty.GetValue(dp);
var binding = new Binding(name)  //Maybe it will work?
{
    Source = frameworkElement
};
```

Comment: I did give it try, and it was close.  I updated my original comment with what I tried and the result.  Thank You!!!!   JD

Comment: You are running into a Reflection Permissions issue.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc.aspx